# Walking glitch in Kingdoms of Amalur: Reckoning

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I recently tried to get back to playing Kingdoms of Amalur: Reckoning on my PS3 after a year-long break and I've run into a strange glitch (as I think of it now, it might have been a reason I stopped playing the game).

Whenever I try to move my character he takes a couple of steps and just freezes mid-step, for as long, as I hold the stick forward.

Only ways to keep moving are:

- change direction of the stick (not always works),
- use dodge to tumble forward,
- release the stick, and move it again.

Please note it's not the question of the game lagging or freezing; it's only my character that stops moving. I'm also sure my controllers (both of them) work fine - I have no problems in any other game with proper functioning of left stick.

I tried to do a search for possible solutions to this bug, but apart from finding some evidence of more people experiencing it, I had no luck. There were mentions of using a save from before the bug appeared, but it's not a solution, really.

Has anyone run across something similar? Is there a solution to this, that would let me continue playing my current save?

Comment: Does the problem persist after fast traveling?

Comment: @CyberSkull Yes it does. I should also note, that I tried deleting the files installed on PS3's HDD (~3.5GB) and reinstalling the game too - still no change.

Comment: This sounds familiar, but I probably rolled back to a much earlier save.